# How can I keep imports lightweight and still properly type annotate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mypy, python-typing

Tensorflow is a super heavy import. I want to import it only when it's needed. However, I have a model loading function like this:

```py
from typing import Dict, Any
from keras.models import Model  # Heavy import! Takes 2 seconds or so!

# Model loading is a heavy task. Only do it once and keep it in memory
model = None  # type: Optional[Model]

def load_model(config: Dict[str, Any], shape) -> Model:
    """Load a model."""
    if globals()['model'] is None:
        globals()['model'] = create_model(wili.n_classes, shape)
        print(globals()['model'].summary())
    return globals()['model']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant will help you:

> if the import is only needed for type annotations in forward references (string literals) or comments, you can write the imports inside `if TYPE_CHECKING`: so that they are not executed at runtime.

> The **TYPE_CHECKING** constant defined by the typing module is **False** at runtime but **True** while type checking.

Example:

```
# foo.py
from typing import List, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    import bar

def listify(arg: 'bar.BarClass') -> 'List[bar.BarClass]':
    return [arg]
```

```
# bar.py
from typing import List
from foo import listify

class BarClass:
    def listifyme(self) -> 'List[BarClass]':
        return listify(self)
```

`TYPE_CHECKING` can also be used to avoid [import cycles](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html#import-cycles).