# Forward references across modules

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In Python typing, circular dependencies can be resolved with a forward reference:

```
class A:
    b: "B"

    def __init__(self, b: "B"):
        self.b = b


class B:
    a: A

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A(self)
```

mypy will typecheck that successfully.

Howerver, if I split `A` and `B` in separate files/modules:

*`a.py:`*

```
class A:
    b: "B"

    def __init__(self, b: "B"):
        self.b = b
```

*`b.py:`*

```
from .a import A


class B:
    a: A

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A(self)
```

And use mypy to check either the modules or the package, it fails:

```
$ mypy -p tt
tt/a.py:2: error: Name 'B' is not defined
tt/a.py:4: error: Name 'B' is not defined
```

Is there a way to resolve that other than by putting both in the same file?

(Tested with Python 3.8.4)

Edit:

For the discussion of circular imports, I added a trivial `__main__.py`:

```
from .b import B

B()
```

And test with `python -m tt`

Comment: You have to import it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this would lead to `ImportError: cannot import name 'B' from partially initialized module 'tt.b' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Comment: Don't use `from module import name` use `import module` then use `module.name`

Comment: Sorry, I still get circular import error messages. If you are certain that will work, can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: To clarify, the circular import errors come from execution with `python`, not `mypy`. I edited the question with a simple test.

Comment: Thanks for marking the canonical duplicate. It's odd, I was so focused on the *forward reference* as the problem, I didn't think to search for cyclic import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I recently [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63128324/13782669) you can use `TYPE_CHECKING` variable:

```
# a.py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .b import B


class A:
    b: "B"

    def __init__(self, b: "B"):
        self.b = b
```

```
# b.py
from .a import A


class B:
    a: A

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A(self)
```